# how to get page views of author page?

Tags: author

I have a question. How can I get the number of page views of the author page?

I mean that I want to get the number of page views to the author page itself, not the total views of all posts on the author page.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress doesn't track page views, so this isn't possible.

You would need to use a plugin or (preferably) an external analytics service to track views. The method of checking views for an author page would then depend on that plugin or service.

Comment: Hi Jacob.Thank you for your advice.

Regarding post&page, I set the meta key and got the page views, but it seems that the author page is impossible. I also considered plugins, but none can track the number of archive(also author) page views.
Do you know which plugins can do that?

Comment: So you're tracking views with your own code? Then you've asked the wrong question. You should be asking how to track view for the author page yourself, and include your code. However, be aware that using post meta to track views is very very bad for database performance and you'd be much better off just using Google Analyics.